# Ao usar fnReloadAjax não permanece na página atual

Tags: ajax, jquery-datatables

Estou usando a [fnReloadAjax](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/api/fnReloadAjax.js) para quando o usuário fazer alguma ação na tabela que é montado com uso do [datatables](https://datatables.net) já recarregue os dados novamente, só que não permanece na página atual.

Esta mantendo o filtro, a ordenação, a quantidade de registros por página, mas sempre volta para a primeira página.

Alguém sabe de alguma coisa para solucionar isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para essa questão cheguei a abrir uma [issue no github](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/issues/294#issuecomment-243437501) sobre esse problema na [página de plugins](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins) do Datatables também e lá me sugeriram usar o método [ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) e foi o que resolveu meu problema, mas lembrando que essa função só esta disponível a partir da versão 1.10 do datatables e para que funcionasse realmente tive que fazer assim:

```
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "data.json"
});

// na chamada de uma ação, qdo precisar recarregar o conteúdo da tabela fiz assim
oTable.api().ajax.reload(null, false);
```